# Mathematical function in device to improve results (CUDA)

Tags: cuda

Is it worth to execute the mathematical function `pow()` in device(GPU), in order to improve the execution time of a code?

I found the function `__powf()` from *Cuda Toolkit Documentation*:
 http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#intrinsic-functions

So I replaced the `pow()` function calls with `__powf()` and I used the option `-use_fast_math` for the compiler, but I got results "nan" instead of double precision numbers. What should I change on my code to achieve the above?

***Libraries of my code.cu:***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>                // for gettimeofday()
#include <time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <cublas.h>
#include "magma.h"
```

***Part of my code.cu:***

```
void function(double *cx, double *cy, double *R, int var, double pts[][2], int e) {

    magma_trans_t my_trans = MagmaNoTrans;
    magma_int_t info; 
    magma_int_t M, C;
    magma_int_t ldda, lddb;

    C = 3;
    M = var;
    int i;
    double Q[M];
    double a[3];
    int ret;
    double A[3][M];
    double pts_x[M], pts_y[M];
    double *dev_pts_x, *dev_pts_y, *devA, *devB, *pWork, lWorkQuery[1]; 

    /* Allocate device memory for the matrix (column-major) */
    ldda = ((M + 31) / 32) * 32;
    lddb = ldda;

    cudaMalloc((void **)&devA, (ldda * C) * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void **)&devB, (M) * sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        pts_x[i] = pts[i][0];
        pts_y[i] = pts[i][1];
        A[0][i] = pts[i][0];
        A[1][i] = pts[i][1];
        A[2][i] = 1.0;
    }   

    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_pts_x, (M) * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_pts_x, pts_x, M * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&dev_pts_y, (M) * sizeof(double));
    cudaMemcpy(dev_pts_y, pts_y, M * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // Kernel invocation
    dim3 threadsPerBlock(1, 1);
    dim3 numBlocks(M / threadsPerBlock.x, M / threadsPerBlock.y);
    call <<< numBlocks, threadsPerBlock >>> (var, dev_pts_x, dev_pts_y, devB);

    cublasSetMatrix(M, C, sizeof(double), A, M, devA, ldda);
    // cublasSetMatrix(M, 1, sizeof(double), B, M, devB, M);

    /* Resolve the LLSP using MAGMA */
    ret = magma_dgels_gpu(my_trans, M, C, 1 , devA, ldda, devB, M, lWorkQuery, -1, &info);

    int lwork = (int)lWorkQuery[0];
    //printf("Optimal work space %d\n", lwork);
    pWork = (double*)malloc((lwork) * sizeof(double)); 

    ret = magma_dgels_gpu(my_trans, M, C, 1, devA, ldda, devB, M, pWork, lwork, &info);

    magma_dgetmatrix(M, 1, devB, lddb, Q, M);

    a[2] = Q[2];
    *cx = Q[0];
    *cy = Q[1];

    *R = sqrt((pow(*cx, 2)+pow(*cy, 2)) - a[2]);
}

__global__ void call(int v, double *pts_x, double *pts_y, double *B) {

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < v) {
        B[i] = -(pow(pts_x[i], 2.0) + pow(pts_y[i], 2.0));
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39390750/681865 - you already asked this question once.....

Comment: I edited today the question, but i saw the "[closed]" tag and i supposed that is better to upload again the question.

Comment: For questions of the type "why isn't this code working?" you are supposed to provde a [mcve]    What you've provided is not a [mcve]   If you're unsure why not, please click the [mcve] link and start reading.  This code is not complete.

Comment: @wasilis: : can you please accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `pow` to square numbers, this is very inefficient.  Use multiplication with an inline function:

```
static inline double square(double x) { return x * x; }
```

You might be getting `NaN` values because the number passed to `pow` is negative. This should not be a problem, but the cuda implementation of `pow` or `__powf` might not support that.

Also note that computing the euclidian distance between two points can be done more directly with the `hypot()` function:

```
double hypot(double x, double y);
```

Finally, as Weather Vane underlined, you might not need to take the square root if all you are interested in is the comparison with another distance computed the same way.

Comment: Also it is not necessary to take a square root if you are only comparing distances, say for sorting or for a depth buffer.

Comment: @WeatherVane: I had no doubt about that ;-), I UVed the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @chqrlie. About NaN values, If i use "pow" cuda returns the expected numbers, but when i use  "__powf" returns NaN.

Comment: Care to share what the expected numbers (and the input to obtain those) are? Makes it a lot easier to help than just stating "it doesn't work".

Comment: @tera: I agree with you, wasilis should provide the numerical values for which the result is `NaN`, I suspect `__powf()` fails on negative numbers, as the comment on the documentation says *derived from its implementation as `exp2f(y * __log2f(x))`*... but using `pow()` is probably not needed at all.

Comment: As noted in comments (@chqrlie : consider propagation into answer itself) , `__powf(x,y)` is simply shorthand for `exp2f(y * __log2f(x))`. The functionality of CUDA math intrinsics was designed to match the corresponding functions in Cg. `__powf()`  therefore does *not* handle the many special cases defined by C/C++ for `pow()` and `powf()`. In addition, the simple fact that double-precision data is being passed to a single-precision function could also  cause trouble, namely the danger of overflow and underflow. Compare also the "CUDA Best Practices Guide",  sections 11.1.4 and 11.1.5.